# How to solve error, "cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Tags: python

My program is similar to this:

```
try:
    age = int(input("age : "))
    xfactor = 10 / age
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print("you didnt enter a valid age")
for ValueError, ZeroDivisionError in range(3):
    print("just try a number")
else:
    print("thank you")
```

I get:

`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

I want the program to send a message when the user makes an incorrect entry for 3 times.

Comment: What does `for ValueError, ZeroDivisionError in range(3):` mean? (Or rather: What did _you_ mean when you wrote it?)

Comment: ...that line is what's causing the error, because you're having the `for` loop first take `0` and then try to run `ValueError, ZeroDivisionError = 0` (if that didn't fail it would next continue to `ValueError, ZeroDivisionError = 1` and the same again with `= 2`, because that's what `for` loops are _supposed to do_). However, `a, b = 0` doesn't make sense, so that `for` syntax doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in `for` loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        age = int(input('age : '))
        xfactor = 10 / age
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print('you didnt enter a valid age')
    else:
        print('thank you')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to iterate over integers(that’s what range() gives you) using exceptions. That part of the code gives you an error. To achieve what I think you want, a while loop would be better. Modified code:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('age : '))
        xfactor = 10 / age
        break
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        counter += 1

    if counter == 3:
        print('you didnt enter a valid age')
        break

print("thank you")
```

In the above code, we first ask the user for input. If the user enter the correct input, we break out of the loop and print “thank you”. If the user enters the incorrect input, we keep asking for input three times, before showing a message.